# Combining Three.js WebGL particles and shaders with mouse movements

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, webgl, cube

I'd really appreciate any sort of advice on how can I accomplish this.

So I've been trying to achieve the result that you can see on the pic.5 . How can flip the bottom shader upside down and change the background so that the particles would be bent inwards (concave cube shape is probably what I need)?

I also attach a link to a desired result.

I tried really hard to research how I can achieve that but to no success sadly.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you guys in advance and please feel free to ask any additional questions.

[screenshot of bottom shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsm8Y.png)

[screenshot of background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxqbU.png)

[link to bottom shader](https://codepen.io/doglink/pen/yLpEBMa)

[link to background](https://codepen.io/doglink/pen/oNEwpWp)

[result i want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2TLY.png)

```
    /*
Most of the stuff in here is just bootstrapping. Essentially it's just
setting ThreeJS up so that it renders a flat surface upon which to draw 
the shader. The only thing to see here really is the uniforms sent to 
the shader. Apart from that all of the magic happens in the HTML view
under the fragment shader.
*/

let container;
let camera, scene, renderer;
let uniforms;

let loader=new THREE.TextureLoader();
let texture;
loader.setCrossOrigin("anonymous");
loader.load(
  'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/982762/noise.png',
  function do_something_with_texture(tex) {
    texture = tex;
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    init();
    animate();
  }
);

function init() {
  container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

  camera = new THREE.Camera();
  camera.position.z = 1;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2, 2 );

  uniforms = {
    u_time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
    u_resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
    u_noise: { type: "t", value: texture },
    u_mouse: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() }
  };

  var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
  } );
  material.extensions.derivatives = true;

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( mesh );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  // renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  onWindowResize();
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

  document.addEventListener('pointermove', (e)=> {
    let ratio = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth;
    uniforms.u_mouse.value.x = (e.pageX - window.innerWidth / 2) / window.innerWidth / ratio;
    uniforms.u_mouse.value.y = (e.pageY - window.innerHeight / 2) / window.innerHeight * -1;
    
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}

function onWindowResize( event ) {
  // renderer.setSize( 1000, 1000 );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  uniforms.u_resolution.value.x = renderer.domElement.width;
  uniforms.u_resolution.value.y = renderer.domElement.height;
}

function animate(delta) {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  render(delta);
}






let capturer = new CCapture( { 
  verbose: true, 
  framerate: 30,
  // motionBlurFrames: 4,
  quality: 90,
  format: 'webm',
  workersPath: 'js/'
 } );
let capturing = false;

isCapturing = function(val) {
  if(val === false && window.capturing === true) {
    capturer.stop();
    capturer.save();
  } else if(val === true && window.capturing === false) {
    capturer.start();
  }
  capturing = val;
}
toggleCapture = function() {
  isCapturing(!capturing);
}

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) { console.log(e.keyCode); if(e.keyCode == 68) toggleCapture(); });

let then = 0;
function render(delta) {
  
  uniforms.u_time.value = -11200 + delta * 0.0015;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  
  if(capturing) {
    capturer.capture( renderer.domElement );
  }
}
```

```
    const nearDist = 0.1;
const farDist = 70000;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
100,
window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
nearDist,
farDist);

camera.position.x = farDist * -200;
camera.position.z = 5000;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setClearColor("BLACK"); // Backgrond Color - Blue
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio); // For HiDPI devices to prevent bluring output canvas
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.querySelector("#canvas-wrapper").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// CREATE CUBES
const cubeSize = 30;
const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize); // BufferAttribute allows for more efficient passing of data to the GPU
const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial(); // Maps the normal vectors to RGB colors
const group = new THREE.Group();
for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  const dist = farDist / 3;
  const distDouble = dist * 2;
  const tau = 6 * Math.PI; // One turn

  mesh.position.x = Math.random() * distDouble - dist;
  mesh.position.y = Math.random() * distDouble - dist;
  mesh.position.z = Math.random() * distDouble - dist;
  mesh.rotation.x = Math.random() * tau;
  mesh.rotation.y = Math.random() * tau;
  mesh.rotation.z = Math.random() * tau;

  // Manually control when 3D transformations recalculation occurs for better performance
  mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
  mesh.updateMatrix();

  group.add(mesh);
}
scene.add(group);

// CREATE TYPOGRAPHY
const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
const textMesh = new THREE.Mesh();
const createTypo = font => {
  const word = "";
  const typoProperties = {
    font: font,
    size: cubeSize,
    height: cubeSize / 2,
    curveSegments: 12,
    bevelEnabled: true,
    bevelThickness: 10,
    bevelSize: 6,
    bevelOffset: 1,
    bevelSegments: 8 };

  const text = new THREE.TextGeometry(word, typoProperties);
  textMesh.geometry = text;
  textMesh.material = material;
  textMesh.position.x = cubeSize * -2;
  textMesh.position.z = cubeSize * -1;
  scene.add(textMesh);
};
loader.load(
"https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json",
createTypo);


// CREATE PART OF THE MOUSE/TOUCH OVER EFFECT
let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;
const mouseFX = {
  windowHalfX: window.innerWidth / 2,
  windowHalfY: window.innerHeight / 2,
  coordinates: function (coordX, coordY) {
    mouseX = (coordX - mouseFX.windowHalfX) * 100;
    mouseY = (coordY - mouseFX.windowHalfY) * 100;
  },
  onMouseMove: function (e) {
    mouseFX.coordinates(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  },
  onTouchMove: function (e) {
    mouseFX.coordinates(e.changedTouches[0].clientX, e.changedTouches[0].clientY);
  } };

document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseFX.onMouseMove, false);
document.addEventListener("touchmove", mouseFX.onTouchMove, false);

// RENDER 3D GRAPHIC
const render = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  // Camera animation
  // Works with onMouseMove and onTouchMove functions
  camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * 0.5;
  camera.position.y += (mouseY * -1 - camera.position.y) * 0.5;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position); // Rotates the object to face a point in world space

  const t = Date.now() * 0.001;
  const rx = Math.sin(t * 0.5) * 0.5;
  const ry = Math.sin(t * 0.5) * 0.5;
  const rz = Math.sin(t * 0.5) * 0.5;
  group.rotation.x = rx;
  group.rotation.y = ry;
  group.rotation.z = rz;
  textMesh.rotation.x = rx;
  textMesh.rotation.y = ry;
  textMesh.rotation.z = rx; // Happy accident :)

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
render();

// RESIZE CANVAS
// This is buggy in some iOS...
// const resizeCanvas = () => {
//  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
//  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
//  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
// };
// window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas, false);
```

Comment: Why there are two render functions? These two snippets are connected to one another or they are independent?

Comment: I found another way to achieve it, but have other problem with particles now :)